# How can I tactfully ask why insiders legally sold stock options?

Tags: inside-information

When recruiters contact me about opportunities, I research LEGAL insider selling online as a metric to assess their company. I know that [insider selling doesn't necessarily evince anything baleful](https://www.thebalance.com/insider-selling-and-your-investments-4134435). Suppose that I *politely* ask a recruiter for the executive's reason for insider selling.

1. If the recruiter evades the question or doesn't answer usefully, then what other proxy or secondary questions can I tactfully ask? Of course I mustn't offend anyone.
2. If a recruiter isn't the executive who sold, and the recruiter honestly doesn't know why the executive did, how can I motivate recruiters to find out?

Comment: Honestly, I think the only way you're going to get answers is if you are in a position of power. And even if people are inclined to answer, I'm not sure how much of a truthful answer you're going to get ("Personal tax reasons" is a common overused reason). I suspect your line of inquiry only makes sense in a very limited set of circumstances, such as stock options being part of your renumeration, or joining a start up. I suspect there is a more broad purpose of your questioning, if you are able to detail that, maybe people can give you answers that help you achieve the underlying purpose.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Thanks. "I suspect there is a more broad purpose of your questioning". Not quite, sorry! I'm just trying to uncover or glean evidence of anything detrimental, before I consider their company.

Comment: What do you mean insiders sell and buy stock for many reasons tax planning etc

Comment: John Lasseter (Pixar, now Disney) used to get $10 million worth of stock options every year and sold them all every year. Apparently he wasn't interested in playing the stock market, but making movies and having a good life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You would never get a useful answer, so you can't.**

If you could reliably extract that kind of information from recruiters, there would be some well-compensated positions at hedge funds for a person of your talents.

I used to do equity research, so I completely understand the alarm bell of insiders selling stock. It has caused me to go back and re-read filings. The kinds of insights you want would have been enormously valuable.

If such insights could be extracted legally (as remember, one might run afoul of insider trading laws as an executive if one is not careful), there are a heck of a lot of people who are going to barge their way to the front of the line for such information.

For you, it determines whether you think your stock options will go up or down or whether you think the company would be stable during a pandemic. For an equity researcher, that information could easily shift multi millions of dollars in capital. The stakes are just so much higher that whatever you would do to get the information, we researchers would do x10.

The fact that insider selling sets off alarm bells also makes the executives want to hide it as much as possible. They aren’t going to tell the recruiter or announce it in an all-hands email.

The recruiter is probably not going to know and certainly isn’t going to be able to find out. Also if you are researching insider selling online, you are probably talking about public companies with hundreds or thousands of employees. The recruiter may never have even met that executive.

Even if you got an answer, I would not expect it to be truthful. There are plenty of innocuous reasons, ranging from tax to kids college. That is a reason, but probably not the key reason.

Comment: Directors share sales and purchases are public documents Investors Chronical lists major ones in the UK